# Postman giving error 422 when passing parameters in POST request to PHP API setup on SLIM framework

Tags: php, postman, slim

I setup a PHP API on Slim 3 framework. I have followed its documents. I am sending POST request from POSTMAN to check it on localhost, being run by XAMPP. But it is giving errors that required parameters are empty or missing though I am giving all the parameters in the POST request, as shown in the attached photo. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65WW8.png)

I have checked the related code in index.php and Dboperations.php , and didn't find any error. The code is also written here:

```
 $app = new \Slim\App([
'settings'=>[
    'displayErrorDetails'=>true
]
]); 


$app->post('/createuser', function(Request $request, Response $response){

if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('firstname', 'surname', 'email', 'fanID', 'deviceLocation'), $request, $response)){

    $request_data = $request->getParsedBody(); 

   
    
    $firstname = $request_data['firstname'];
    $surname = $request_data['surname'];
    $email = $request_data['email'];
    $fanID = $request_data['fanID'];
    $deviceLocation = $request_data['deviceLocation'];

    $db = new DbOperations; 

    $result = $db->createUser($firstname, $surname, $email, $fanID, $deviceLocation);
    
    if($result == USER_CREATED){

        $message = array(); 
        $message['error'] = false; 
        $message['message'] = 'User created successfully';

        $response->write(json_encode($message));

        return $response
                    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                    ->withStatus(201);

    }else if($result == USER_FAILURE){

        $message = array(); 
        $message['error'] = true; 
        $message['message'] = 'Some error occurred';

        $response->write(json_encode($message));

        return $response
                    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                    ->withStatus(422);    

    }else if($result == USER_EXISTS){
        $message = array(); 
        $message['error'] = true; 
        $message['message'] = 'User Already Exists';

        $response->write(json_encode($message));

        return $response
                    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                    ->withStatus(422);    
    }
}

return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->withStatus(422);    

});

function haveEmptyParameters($required_params, $request, $response){
    $error = false; 
    $error_params = '';
    $request_params = $request->getParsedBody(); 

    foreach($required_params as $param){
    if(!isset($request_params[$param]) || strlen($request_params[$param])<=0){
        $error = true; 
        $error_params .= $param . ', ';
    
    }
    }

    if($error){
      $error_detail = array();
      $error_detail['error'] = true; 
      $error_detail['message'] = 'Required parameters ' . substr($error_params, 0, -2) . ' are 
      missing or empty';
    $response->write(json_encode($error_detail));
    }
return $error; 


 }

 $app->run();
```

I have used the same parameters e.g firstname,surname etc in Dboperations.php file so I am not attaching the code from that php script.Kindly consider guiding me on this problem.

Comment: The `public/` directory is the DocumentRoot of your webserver and must not be part of the URL. You may fix this first using `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I tried with this also after changing the .htaccess file, I am getting this error:                  The requested URL was not found on this server.